# How to add External .jar from JFreeChart files to BlueJ?

Tags: java, jar, jfreechart, package, bluej

I am doing a program in which I calculate the distance between 2 points in a 3-dimensional space. Now I need JFreeChart to plot the line formed by these 2 points on an XYZ axis. Also, this program needs to be run on another computer with BlueJ, hence I want to import the JFreeChart library in form of a package. But I wasn't even able to add it as external .jars from Tools\Preferences\Libraries(*Yes*, I did restart BlueJ). So please tell me how to do this, specifically as a package. Thanks in advance. a part of my code follows:

```
String Sx1,Sx2,Sy1,Sy2,Sz1,Sz2;
                Sx1=tAX.getText();
                Sy1=tAY.getText();
                Sz1=tAZ.getText();
                Sx2=tBX.getText();
                Sy2=tBY.getText();
                Sz2=tBZ.getText();
                double mx,xi,yi,zi,x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,px,py,pz,dXY,dist,c,mz,cmain,c2;
                double re1;
                boolean v1=false,v2=false,v3=false,v4=false;
                x1=Integer.parseInt(Sx1);
                y1=Integer.parseInt(Sy1);
                z1=Integer.parseInt(Sz1);
                x2=Integer.parseInt(Sx2);
                y2=Integer.parseInt(Sy2);
                z2=Integer.parseInt(Sz2);
                px=Math.abs(x2-x1);
                py=Math.abs(y2-y1);
                pz=Math.abs(z2-z1);
                dXY=Math.sqrt((px*px)+(py*py));
                dist=Math.sqrt((dXY*dXY)+(pz*pz));

                mx=py/px;
                mz=py/pz;

                c=y1-(mx*x1);
                c2=y1-(mz*z1);

                JFrame f2=new JFrame("Answers");
                f2.setSize(600,600);
                f2.setVisible(true);
                f2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                Dimension dim=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
                f2.setLocation(dim.width/2-f2.getSize().width/2,dim.height/2-f2.getSize().height/2);

                JPanel p2=new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

                JLabel L1=new JLabel("The distance between the two points is "+dist);
                gbc.insets=new Insets(5,5,5,5);
                gbc.gridx=0;
                gbc.gridy=1;
                p2.add(L1,gbc);

                JLabel L2=new JLabel("The slope of the line on the x axis is  "+mx);
                gbc.insets=new Insets(5,5,5,5);
                gbc.gridx=0;
                gbc.gridy=2;
                p2.add(L2,gbc);

                if(c!=0)
                {
                    JLabel L3=new JLabel("The equation of the line on the XY plane is: y="+mx+"x+"+c);
                    gbc.insets=new Insets(5,5,5,5);
                    gbc.gridx=0;
                    gbc.gridy=3;
                    p2.add(L3,gbc);
                }
                else 
                {
                    JLabel L3=new JLabel("The equation of the line on the XY plane is: y="+mx+"x");
                    gbc.insets=new Insets(5,5,5,5);
                    gbc.gridx=0;
                    gbc.gridy=3;
                    p2.add(L3,gbc);
                }

                if(c2!=0)
                {
                    JLabel L4=new JLabel("The equation of the line on the YZ plane is: y="+mz+"z+"+c2);
                    gbc.insets=new Insets(5,5,5,5);
                    gbc.gridx=0;
                    gbc.gridy=4;
                    p2.add(L4,gbc);
                }
                else 
                {
                    JLabel L4=new JLabel("The equation of the line on the YZ plane is: y="+mz+"z");
                    gbc.insets=new Insets(5,5,5,5);
                    gbc.gridx=0;
                    gbc.gridy=4;
                    p2.add(L4,gbc);
                }



                f2.add(p2);
```

In this I need to plot the line as per the 2 equations. Any advice about that would be nice too!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can always run programs from command prompt / terminal window and specify your external JAR-files with start script (here's example in Windows environment):

```
C:> java -classpath C:\java\MyClasses\myclasses.jar utility.myapp.Cool
```

As for a second option I am not sure if BlueJ makes libraries in its catalog Tools\Preferences\Libraries available to programs you start with it. I assume BlueJ has some way in IDE itself to add external libraries (that have been packaged into JAR-files) into the Java classpath when starting a program .

Comment: Thanks, but what does the C:> stand for?

Comment: It's the C-drive or default name for hard disk on Windows operation system. The command itself starts with 'java ...' that you have to type. What operation system are you working on? In Unix-based environments it usually shows your name instead of this C:> and/or combination of dollar sign and current catalog.